# Show $M=\{(x,y):y\geq x^2\}$ is a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

> Show that the following set is convex. $$M = \left\{ (x,y) : y \geq x^2 \right\}$$

---

First I take two arbitrary points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2) \in M$. Then I need to show that

$$\lambda(x_1,y_1)+[1-\lambda](x_2,y_2)= (\lambda x_1 + (1 − \lambda) x_2, \lambda y_1 + (1 − \lambda) y_2 ) \in M$$

After that I have no clue what I have to do. Thanks for your support.

Comment: You could use that $x\mapsto x^2$ is a convex function.

Comment: You have not used the definition of M

Comment: You need to show that $\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2) \ge (\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two points in $M$, say, $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. You need to prove that
$$(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2, \lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2) \in M \Leftrightarrow  \lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2 \geq \left( \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2\right)^2$$
For every $\lambda \in (0,1)$.
The right side is $$\left( \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2\right)^2 \leq \lambda x_1^2 + (1-\lambda)x_2^2 \leq \lambda y_1+(1-\lambda) y_2$$
Here i used the convexity of $x^2$ on the first inequality, since $(x^2)'' = 2$ and the fact that $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

One more general result is that the epigraph of a function is convex iff the function is convex.

Comment: How did you know $(λ$x_1$+(1−λ)$x_2$)^2$≤$λ^2$$x_1^2$+$(1−λ)^2$$x_1^2$)?

Comment: @JuanSebastian This is the convexity of $x\mapsto x^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

As I feel OP needs technical details, so, meanwhile usually it is shown using derivative let me show everything directly here, for which divide question in 2 parts:

1. Directly prove convexity of $f(x)=x^2 $: lets take $0 \leqslant \lambda_1,\lambda_2\leqslant 1$ and $\lambda_1 +\lambda_2 =1$ numbers.
   $$\lambda_1 x_1^2 + \lambda_2 x_2^2 \geqslant \left( \lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2\right)^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
   \lambda_1 x_1^2 + \lambda_2 x_2^2 \geqslant \lambda_1^2 x_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 x_2^2 +2\lambda_1  \lambda_2 x_1 x_2 \Leftrightarrow \\
   \lambda_1  \lambda_2 x_1^2 + \lambda_1  \lambda_2 x_2 ^2 \geqslant 2\lambda_1  \lambda_2 x_1 x_2
   $$
2. Prove, that for convex function set $\text{epi}(f) =\{(x,y):y \geqslant f(x)  \}$ is convex (it's your $M$). For this lets take again $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ such as above and $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2) \in \text{epi}(f)$, where $f(x)=x^2 $. Then we have
   $$ y=\lambda_1 y_1 + \lambda_2 y_2 \geqslant \lambda_1 f(x_1) + \lambda_2 f(x_1) \geqslant f\left(\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2 x_2\right)=f(x) $$
   So $(x,y) \in \text{epi}(f)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x\\ x & y\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{2}$$

Using [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), we get $y \geq 0$ and $y \geq x^2$, Note that the former is redundant. Hence, the [epigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics)) of function $x \mapsto x^2$ is a [spectrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron) and, thus, convex.

---

[convex-analysis](/questions/tagged/convex-analysis) [linear-matrix-inequality](/questions/tagged/linear-matrix-inequality) [spectrahedra](/questions/tagged/spectrahedra)